# ResXFileCodeGeneratorEx is not working for Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, resx

I use ResXFileCodeGeneratorEx for generating ids. This was working till the time I used Visual Studio 2010 IDE but it is not working for Visual Studio 2017.

Please help for the same.

Answer (score 2):

Extension for Visual Studio 2019 can be [found here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=lloyd.ResxCodeFileGeneratorExVS2019)

Extension for Visual Studio 2017 can be [found here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=LongLiang.ExtendedStronglyTypedResourceGenerator-18702)

Answer (score 1):

The deleted answer to this question pointed to the location of a newly built ResXFileCodeGeneratorEx but was deleted because it only contained a single link and no context. I'm not the original answerer, but figured that it may still be valuable to have this information:

It seems to have been renamed to [ResXCodeFileGeneratorEx](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=LongLiang.ExtendedStronglyTypedResourceGenerator-18702), and if you search through the menu in Visual Studio under Tools > Extension and Updates, you need to search for "Extended Strongly Typed Resource Generator".

However, the internal name is still the same, so the Custom Tool action should remain `ResXFileCodeGeneratorEx`.

I'm not aware whether or not it works on Visual Studio 2019, but since [the original source is still around](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13830/Extended-Strongly-Typed-Resource-Generator), it oughtn't be too hard to resolve that yourself if you need it.

To install it, simply doubleclick the VSIX file, it will popup with the VS Version Instance Selector, where you can select to which of your VS 2017 instances (pro, community, preview) you want to install the extension to.